# Параметры поста Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Все кто мало-мальски ковырялся в исходниках `wordpress`, знают что для каждого материала существует ряд функций, таких как

```
the_title(); 
the_content();
```

и т.д. Они работают на основе '

```
get'еров get_the_content() & get_the_title()
```

Хотелось бы узнать где найти список ВСЕХ таких `'get'еров` , иначе всех стандартных полей материала. Понимаю что это должно быть в кодексе, но так и не нашел, только отдельные описания функция для названия, контента, автора даты и т.д. Но судя по таблицам базы данных там есть еще и другие интересные параметры.

Comment: гляньте здесь [http://wp-docs.ru][1]


  [1]: http://wp-docs.ru

Comment: спасибо за сайт, неплохой. Но хотелось бы все же получить именно список гетеров для свойств поста, или сам список свойств.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все свойства/поля/геттеры описаны в основном классе [WP_Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) ([исходник с комментариями](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/post.php#L0))

Comment: то что надо! спасибо